# Field Level Security information via REST API

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, tooling-api, workbench

Is there a way to access FLS via `REST API` or `Apex`? I'm trying to find out what FLS profile are `Visible` and what are `Read-only`. I couldn't find much info online.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use REST API to perform a [query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) on [FieldPermissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) object.

For example to get FLS for `System Administrator` on all `Account` fields perform the following query

```
select Id, SObjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
from FieldPermissions
where parentid in (
    select id
    from permissionset
    where IsOwnedByProfile= true 
        and PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
    )
and SObjectType = 'Account'
```